# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type void

Tags: angular

> Property 'sucribe' Doesnot exist on type void. I not  use void
> anywhere,but I remove void from ngOnInit(),but why i am getting this
> type of error Property 'sucribe' Doesnot exist on type void., I
> restart my vsCode,and refresh it but still getting same error.  here
> below i describe my code strctures
>
> productlist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductdataService } from '../service/data/productdata.service';

export class Product{
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public product : String,
    public price : number,
    public orderdate : Date,
    public deliverdate : Date,
    public done : boolean
  ){

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productlist',
  templateUrl: './productlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productlist.component.css']
})
export class ProductlistComponent implements OnInit {
  proudLists : Product[];
 
  constructor(private prodataservice : ProductdataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.prodataservice.retriveAllProducts('Printer')
      .subscribe(
        response =>{
          console.log(response);
          this.proudLists=response;
        }
      )
  }

}
```

> productdata.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from 'src/app/productlist/productlist.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductdataService {

  constructor(private htp:HttpClient ) { }
  retriveAllProducts(productname){
    this.htp.get<Product[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${productname}/prodct`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
retriveAllProducts(productname){
  this.htp.get<Product[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${productname}/prodct`)
```

To:

```
retriveAllProducts(productname){
  return this.htp.get<Product[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${productname}/prodct`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot 2 things in your service method, the type of the method and the return:

Before :

```
retriveAllProducts(productname){
this.htp.get<Product[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${productname}/prodct`)
```

}

After :

```
retriveAllProducts(productname<Product[]>){
return this.htp.get<Product[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${productname}/prodct`)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can `Subscribe` an `observable` only. Add return statement before the service call to return an observable from it.

```
return this.htp.get<Product[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/${productname}/prodct`);
```